# Printer menu different between 2 ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, printing

I got two samsung new series 9, 13', the very same, with Ubuntu 12.10 installed on it (Erratum : The second one [SEEMS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254327/ubuntu-says-13-04-but-lsb-release-says-12-10#comment318438_254327) to have **13.04** installed on it, but same kernel **3.5.0-23**). I installed the MP495 printer driver on both :

```
$ dpkg -l | grep 495
rc  scangearmp-mp495series 1.60-1 amd64   ScanGear MP for Linux.
```

But one can print, and the other one cannot. Indeed, I found something weird :
[image: Here is the printer menu on laptop N°1 - working]

And here is the printer menu on laptop N°2, not working :
[image]

What's wrong with this N°2 ? never seen such printing menu before...

So I can't follow the usual procedure to add a new printer, and can't print from this N°2 laptop (wifi printing).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did they both have the same version of Ubuntu installed at the same time?

Comment: I was shure they were same version, but actually they are NOT ! One is 12.10, and the other one (N°2) is 13.04...Now, I'm wondering how did I manage to upgrade one of them on the latest 13.04 without even noticing it !!!

Comment: How can I revert back to 12.10 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3. I got it back to normal by running :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Found the answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254327/ubuntu-says-13-04-but-lsb-release-says-12-10/254341#comment318767_254341).