# Ubuntu says 13.04 but lsb_release says 12.10

Tags: 12.10, 13.04

During investigations on my Samsung New Series 9 with 12.10 installed on it, I found this :
[image]

- Settings > details > Ubuntu 13.04
- lsb_release > ubuntu 12.10

Is that possible ? I really think [my printing problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253147/printer-menu-different-between-2-ubuntu-12-10) is related to this inconsistency...

Thank you.

[Edit]

```
root@jocelyne-ss9:/home/jocelyne# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all

root@jocelyne-ss9:/home/jocelyne# for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-quantal.list:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-quantal.list.save:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list.save:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi.list:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://download.jitsi.org/deb unstable/


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi.list.save:

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://download.jitsi.org/deb unstable/


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-quantal.list:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scopes-packagers-ppa-quantal.list:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scopes-packagers-ppa-quantal.list.save:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/scopes-packagers/ppa/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list:

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main #Added by software-center
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main #Added by software-center


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list.save:

# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main #Added by software-center
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main #Added by software-center


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/umang-indicator-stickynotes-quantal.list:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu quantal main


** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/umang-indicator-stickynotes-quantal.list.save:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu quantal main

root@jocelyne-ss9:/home/jocelyne# apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center:
  Installé : 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu11~ubuntu12.10.1
  Candidat : 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu11~ubuntu12.10.1
  Table de version :
 *** 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu11~ubuntu12.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.4.2-0ubuntu19 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: the OP has clearly stated that he's using 12.10.

Comment: OK, thanks, I obviously mis read the question, my mistake

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done` -- this should shed light on whether or not you're using any software sources that might give you files from 13.04.

Comment: thank you, I added the output. Not sure about conclusions though..

Comment: Installing **Ubuntu 13.04 beta** will cause this (or similar). *Until actual release of **13.04** (in April 2013), the download is still labelled **12.10**, but with a later kernel, new libraries, and other extras.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lsb_release` gets its information from `/etc/lsb-release`, provided by package `base-files`, while `gnome-control-center` simply displays the PNG file at `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png`, which is distributed in package `gnome-control-center-data`.

Check which  `gnome-control-center-data` you are using with the following command:

```
apt-cache policy gnome-control-center
```

It may be a version from a PPA or some other source that you may have installed; depending on the outcome of the above command you may decide you want to purge the PPA, or reinstall the package, or ignore the reported version mismatch...

In any case, you seem to be running 12.10 with at least one file from 13.04.

Comment: The package is from `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`, not the quantal repositories. You can get it back to normal if you want by running `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` and `sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`. Any updates from that PPA will be reverted - make sure that is what you want to do beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the 12.10 version installed?

For me it says 12.10.

The only case I have here that shows like that is the 13.04 which is still in development (Ans also consider off-topic in Askubuntu):

[image]

If you installed some 13.04 packages (Either manually or via a PPA) it might have mixed the whole 12.10 with 13.04 packages and modified the System information to show the information as you see it now.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I have the 12.10, definitly ! However as you said, it is surely some PPA from 13.04 that mixed the whole...I edited my post with some command output. Thank you for your answer.