# Why does Ubuntu 12.10 update to 13.04 on its own?

Tags: 12.10, updates, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.10, after few minutes of working I've got an Update and allowed it.

After this I see that Ubuntu has been upgraded to 13.04. Why?

I am not a developer, just try to work.

In Software sources in one of tabs there is an  `extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` repo. 
Is this responsible for updates to 13.04? If I disable those will the problem be gone?

Comment: Where do you see it is 13.04?

Comment: in system details and few things are diferent

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the right ISO file? Did you get your download from http://www.ubuntu.com/download ?

Comment: It doesn't.  If you think it has, you will have to be more specific about why.

Comment: i download Ubuntu 12.10 x64 from ubuntu download site. all I want to know is why my Ubuntu after each install updates to 13.04 version

Comment: If the information [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254327/ubuntu-says-13-04-but-lsb-release-says-12-10) *doesn't* reveal the source of this problem, then it's a bug and should be [reported as such](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). See also [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) ([At least once before](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/690248), information from a newer release's help was wrongly synced into an older release's help. It affected many users. It was reported as a bug, then fixed.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for Your respond :) now I know this happed when I was making Nautilus 3.6 by:

"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3"

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that its automatic update as 13.04 on beta

Because the ubuntu 13.04 is still on beta test , so it's not offcial released if you want to update to ubuntu 13.04 beta

open terminal , and type this   ( this is the easiest way )

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

any way its not bad to test beta as on 27 april its offcial released and u can update it